# Make data member accessible everywhere, but read-only

Tags: c++, oop

I'm just starting my own Windows API wrapper and I've run into an unfamiliar topic while rewriting a structure to include C++ features.

I'm turning this:

```
typedef struct _RECT {
    LONG left;
    LONG top;
    LONG right;
    LONG bottom;
} RECT, *PRECT;
```

into

```
#define RECT_POS 1
#define RECT_SIZE 2

typedef struct WrapperRect // RECT
{
    WrapperRect(); // all 0
    WrapperRect (const double, const double, const double, const double, bool = RECT_POS); // initalize with tl pos and either br pos or size

    bool set (const double, const double, const double, const double, bool = RECT_POS); // set tl pos and either br pos or size
    bool pos (const double, const double); // set tl pos
    bool size (const double, const double); // set size

    WrapperRect & operator= (const WrapperRect &); // assign another rect
    bool operator== (const WrapperRect &); // check for equality (pos+size)
    bool operator!= (const WrapperRect &); // check for inequality (pos+size)
    bool operator> (const WrapperRect &); // check for tl pos greater
    bool operator< (const WrapperRect &); // check for tl pos less
    bool operator>= (const WrapperRect &); // check for tl pos greater equal
    bool operator<= (const WrapperRect &); // check for tl pos less equal
    WrapperRect & operator+ (const POINT &); // move down/right
    WrapperRect & operator- (const POINT &); // move up/left
    WrapperRect & operator+= (const POINT &); // move down/right
    WrapperRect & operator-= (const POINT &); // move up/left

    double l, left, x; // left
    double r, right; // right
    double t, top, y; // top
    double b, bottom; // bottom

    double w, width; // width
    double h, height; // height
} Rect, rect; // allow more convenient names
```

My only problem is that if the user were to say

```
Rect myRect;  
myRect.right = 50;
```

it will set the right side, but won't be able to change the aliases for the right side, or the width.

I don't want the members to be private either because I want the

```
cout << myRect.x;
```

syntax rather than the annoying

```
cout << myRect.getX();
```

syntax.
Is there any way to achieve this, or must I use get functions?

edit:
I really wasn't thinking when I wrote this, I've added some return values (>.>) and changed the double in operator+ etc to a point. I'm starting to try the possibilities before I accept one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite bad practice to expose your data members. It is also really bad practice to have multiple copies of the exact same information inside your classes. It is both inefficient and bug-prone.

You definitely need to use accessor functions.

That being said, you don't need to have getX(); - just x() would be fine.

If you're really set on avoiding function syntax, something like this would be *ok* I guess:

```
struct Rect
{
private:
    double l, r, t, b;

public:
    const double &x, &y;

    Rect() : x(r), y(t) {}

    ...etc.
};
```

Then you could use `r.x` in a safe fashion though you are still somewhat exposing your implementation.

Comment: After a stupid error coming out of define statements I finally got it compiling and it works great, thanks. Don't worry about the bad practices here; I'm only using it for my own small programs development.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that exposed const references can be made read-write with const_cast.

Comment: Also worth noting that they should be `const volatile`.  Without the volatile, your compiler may move the "read of x" before some other write-of-r that would have otherwise logically appeared in the reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

You should use get functions. You don't want the syntax you claim you want.

For example, suppose you later change the function to encode both the x and they y values together into some complex structure. How will you make `myRect.x` work then?

Say retrieving the value of `x` is rare. So you don't want to compute it unless you have to. How will you make `myRect.x` work then?

Say at some point in the future, you need to count how many times `x` has been accessed. How will you make `myRec.x` work then?

Use get functions so that you don't force code that just wants to get the value of x to understand how it's stored inside the class.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a constant pointer.  `const double * xPtr;` then initialize it in the constructor: `xPtr = &x` this creates a pointer to `x` that cannot be used to modify `x`.  You would definitely need a setter function, though to change the value `x` itself.

As has been noted, this is bad practice and you're better off using a class with private members, accessors, etc.

`const` pointer types reference here:

http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/general/article.php/c6967

Answer (score 0):

This might not earn me a lot of coding cred' but I actually don't think that it's *such* bad style to access members directly when what you're creating is very much like a c struct that is responsible mostly for storing data and not responsible for a higher level of intelligence. So the answer to your question is to use a union

```
struct rect
{
    union
    {
        double width;
        double w;
    };

    union
    {
        double height;
        double h;
    };
}
```

When you do this, then accessing h and accessing height actually access the same location in memory.